# How to @Inject into Kotlin Builder classes with Dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

My current Android project employs a number of Kotlin data classes that employ builders to construct them.

I wish to inject an instance into the Kotlin data class.

Each of my data classes have this basic structure

```
data class MyDataKlass(    val onError: Consumer<in Throwable>,
                           val onComplete: Action,
                           val dbController: DatabaseController,
                           val lnController: ILoginNetworkController) : BaseSO() {

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    fun execute() {

    }

}

fun myFunction(block: MyDataKlassBuilder.() -> Unit): MyDataKlass = MyDataKlassBuilder().apply(block).build()

class MyDataKlassBuilder {

    var onError: Consumer<in Throwable> = Consumer { }
    var onComplete: Action = Action { }
    lateinit var dbController: DatabaseController
    lateinit var lnController: ILoginNetworkController

    fun build(): MyDataKlass = MyDataKlass(onError, onComplete, dbController, lnController)
}
```

I employ these classes as follows:-

```
 val myFunction = myFunction {
                onComplete = Action { syncWorkerResult = Result.success() }
                dbController = databaseController
                lnController = loginNetwork
                onError = Consumer {
                    syncWorkerResult = Result.failure()
                }
            }

 myFunction.execute()
```

Currently I am passing in my database (`DatabaseController`) and network(`ILoginNetworkController`) controllers into the Builders of the Kotlin Data classes

I wish to @Inject them to make my code "cleaner"

I can @Inject both into my Activities and Repositories but cannot see how to employ Dagger to inject them into the above Data Classes.

Is it possible to @Inject into Kotlin Data Classes?

Comment: I think the lie here is that this shouldn't be a data class, because it's not `data`, it does things such as `execute()` potentially asynchronous operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried this syntax on a data class, but it may be the good one:

```
data class MyDataKlass @Inject constructor(
    val onError: Consumer<in Throwable>,
    val onComplete: Action,
    val dbController: DatabaseController,
    val lnController: ILoginNetworkController
) : BaseSO() {
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    fun execute() {
    }
}
```

and in your activity:

```
lateinit var dataKlass: MyDataKlass @Inject set
```

Of course, your dependency graph will have to specify how to provide all the parameters of the data class.

Comment: I cannot see how I can @Provide my data Klasses and still build(er) them using different values. Does Dagger allow this? For instance I have to pass a unique key into my data classes each time I use them.

Comment: Depends how your app is architectured. For instance, if you have a scoped subcomponent per screen, you can just provide that key in the relevant module / submodule. Otherwise, you can find a way injecting a given key using `@Named` annotation. Another way to use the same data class structure, but with specific attributes, would be to extend `MyDataKlass` to have a specific concrete type that Dagger could to differenciate.